# EF Migrations in Hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity framework with multiple existing databases which are in a hierarchy.

- 1x Parent
- 3x Children

I aim to have two database contexts, one to support the parent and one to support the children. I also intend to have automatic migrations setup and enabled on both contexts.

My child contexts pass in the connection string name to determine which child connection to create

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a child database context within a hierarchy
/// </summary>
public class ChildDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ChildDbContext(string name) : base(name)
    {

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ChildDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

}
```

**Question**

Will automatic migrations update each child database the first time it is accessed i.e the first time I do `new ChildDbContext("Child1")`, `new ChildDbContext("Child2")`, `new ChildDbContext("Child3")`?

I'm not 100% sure when the migration check is actually performed or whether it would work without a parameterless contructor.

Answer (score 0):

EF determines whether a database needs to be initialized by checking a dictionary for a key which is generated from the connection type and connection string. All that to say that migrations should be performed for each database.

*See `InitializeDatabaseAction` in [`System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Internal/LazyInternalContext.cs)*